# Overwriting span tag when getting span data from another location

Tags: html, css

I have this HubL code (HubSpot): {{ post.summary }}. This pulls the summary of each blog post and adds it to wherever I put the HubL, in my case for an email.

However, it doesn't just pull the text, it pulls the  the text sits it along with it's CSS. I.e.

```
<span style="font-size: 1.25rem;">
   This text here sits in the blog post.
</span>
```

In emails, I **do not want** the `summary` to be `font-size: 1.25rem`, I want it to be `14px`.

I thought simply styling the `<p>` the `summary` sits in within the email would work:

```
<p style="font-size: 14px;">{{ post.summary }}</p>
```

But for some reason, the 1.25rem size still is visible.

Is there a way to overwrite the size that I'm missing?

Comment: post.summary is controlled by backend, can't you do this on backend? Or you still want a front-end method to remove the 1.25em?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Style within the span from within the blog summary. Set the font in the stylesheet for the blog. It shouldn't pull through when calling the blog summary using HubL. Alternatively, refer to the [documentation](http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/hubl/intro-to-hubl) on how to remove HTML that is being pulled through using HubL.

Answer (score 0):

The `rem` unit is relative to the font size of the root element. If an element has its font-size set using that unit, then changing the font-size of its parent element is going to have no effect.

Modify the content of `post.summary` instead, either in the place that the data is sourced from in the first place or while it is in the variable. (Since you said this is for an email, you can't use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM after the page has loaded, which would have been the ugliest solution anyway).